# Why this onchange select option and function run multiple jQuery [very confused]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I run function after select option change, but why the function run multiple after select option multiple change to.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '#bbp_forum_id', function(e) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    select_value(value);
  });

  var select_value = function(value) {
    $('#bbp_topic_tags').on('keyup', function() {
      console.log($(this).val() + value);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="bbp_forum_id" id="bbp_forum_id" tabindex="103">
  <option value="0">Select...</option>
  <option value="6">A</option>
  <option value="8">B</option>
  <option value="4">C</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="bbp_topic_tags" />
```

**Do it, please:**
Select option multiple (first: select A, then B, and C) and write something in text input. See console log, you can see function run multiple. Why?

I want get ONLY last selected value and don't run function multipe. See live here: https://jsfiddle.net/2Lpfgra6/1/

Comment: Because you're adding a new `keyup` event handler on each `change` of the `<select>`

Comment: The issue is because you're attaching a new `keyup` event handler *every time the select is changed*. To solve this you just need to remove the `change` event handler and attached the `keyup` handler on load.

Comment: Rory McCorsan, can you give me example?

Comment: I added an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're attaching a new `keyup` event handler *every time the select is changed*.

To solve this you just need to remove the `change` event handler and attach the `keyup` handler on load. You can then read the value from the `select` when each key is pressed, like this:

```js
$('#bbp_topic_tags').on('keyup', function() {
  console.log($(this).val() + $('#bbp_forum_id').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="bbp_forum_id" id="bbp_forum_id" tabindex="103">
  <option value="0">Select...</option>
  <option value="6">A</option>
  <option value="8">B</option>
  <option value="4">C</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="bbp_topic_tags" />
```

Comment: Works! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here issue is when ever your changing the dropdown your adding new `keyup` event to input.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(document).on('change', '#bbp_forum_id', function(e) {
        var value = $('#bbp_forum_id').val();
        select_value(value);
      });

      $('#bbp_topic_tags').on('keyup', function() {
       console.log($(this).val() + $('#bbp_forum_id').val());
      });


      var select_value = function(value) {
        console.log($('#bbp_topic_tags').val() + value);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, this code work to. but i need with simple solutions., :)